# Alternative approach to gmapping and hector-mapping?

Tags: navigation, odometry, mapping, laser, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

i'm new to this forum and hope to ask my question the right way.

I started to work with ROS. To get used to it i tested some SLAM algorithm to get a occupancy grid map.
The first one was gmapping(http:// wiki.ros.org/ gmapping), the second one was
hector_mapping(http:// wiki.ros.org/ hector_slam), both worked fine for me.

Now im searching for some other algorithm for comparsion and wanted to ask if you can commend some others.
They should be easy to use like gmapping and hector_mapping.
Im using laserdata and odometry but its not neccessary that the algorithm using both.

Thanks for your help.

Sascha

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/141616/alternative-approach-to-gmapping-and-hector-mapping?/) by [GermanStudent](https://answers.ros.org/users/13521/germanstudent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-03-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably late to answer I guess, Try [rtabmap_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros).

---

Originally posted by [R@m](https://answers.ros.org/users/25832/r@m/) with karma: 98 on 2016-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

SLAM Karto (https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_karto) is another option, but it's not well documented on the ROS wiki.

You might also be interested in this paper (I'm not affiliated): ["An Evaluation of 2D SLAM Techniques Available
in ROS"](http://home.isr.uc.pt/%7Edavidbsp/publications/SPR_SSRR2013_SLAM.pdf)

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-09-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2